# Is it possible to place legend key numbers inside elements of a ggplot legend?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to plot an area on a map for data that has very long label names. I've tried a work around of creating a concatenation of an id (rownames) to the values of the labels so that only the short id appears on the map, but so that the legend serves as a key (id: name). I'm wondering if there is a more elegant way to solve this problem, such as having the id shown inside of the box element and having only the name to the right of the box. Below is a minimum reproducible example.

```
library(sf)
library(ggplot2)
library(gtools)
library(dplyr)

nc <- sf::st_read(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package = "sf"), quiet = TRUE)
nc$id <- as.numeric(rownames(nc))

nc <- dplyr::mutate(nc, field_key = paste(id, NAME, sep = ": "))

ggplot2::ggplot(nc) +
  geom_sf(aes(color = field_key)) +
  geom_sf_text(aes(label = id)) +
  scale_color_discrete(breaks = gtools::mixedsort(nc$field_key))
```

[image]

Changing the following line gives an "a" inside of the box, but it's unclear to me why, or whether it's possible to manipulate the a to the id number instead.

```
geom_sf_text(aes(label = id, color = 'white'))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is the result you want:

[image]

But I'm afraid obtaining it isn't very elegant. Basically, I have just shifted the legend text to the left, with some spaces prepended to keep the numbers aligned.

```r
library(sf)
library(ggplot2)
library(gtools)
library(dplyr)

nc <- sf::st_read(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package = "sf"), quiet = TRUE)
nc$id <- as.numeric(rownames(nc))


nc <- dplyr::mutate(nc, field_key = paste0(c(rep("   ", 9), rep(" ", 90), ""), 
                                           paste(id, NAME, sep = ":     ")),
                    field_key = factor(field_key, levels = field_key))
      
ggplot2::ggplot(nc) +
  geom_sf(aes(color = field_key)) +
  geom_sf_text(aes(label = id)) +
  scale_color_discrete(breaks = gtools::mixedsort(nc$field_key)) +
  theme(legend.text = element_text(margin = margin(0, 0, 0, -24)),
        legend.key.width = unit(20, "points"))
```

Comment: I ended up adding a nested an ifelse so that it would work with a varying number of rows (up to 100): nc <- nc %>% dplyr::mutate(id = as.numeric(rownames(.))) %>%  dplyr::mutate(field_key = ifelse(id < 10, paste0('   ', id, '   ', NAME), ifelse(ID < 100, paste0(' ', id, '   ', NAME), paste0(id, '   ', NAME))), field_key = factor(field_key, levels = field_key))